# Dropping this riddle here

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Used in bluegrass,
>   no woodwind, no brass;
>   but have some class,
>   don't rhyme me with gas.
>
> Anglers I face,
>   in ocean's embrace;
>   but in this case,
>   don't rhyme me with space.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This deep, fishy riddle sounds like

> **bass**

Used in bluegrass, no woodwind, no brass;

> the stringed instrument which emits low-pitched sounds

but have some class, don't rhyme me with gas.

> in this case it rhymes with base/space.

Anglers I face, in ocean's embrace;

> bass - various species of fish, such as the sea bass.

but in this case, don't rhyme me with space

> here pronounced to rhyme with class/gas.

Comment: A [rafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafe) is a diacritic, 
which is not safe to rhyme with jafe;
it makes [Pe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe_(letter)) be pronounced as fey, 
which rhymes with café but not jafe.

Comment: And rot13(gur gvgyr ersref gb "qebc gur onff")

Comment: Bonus question: How is the user's name pronounced? The first way? The second way? Or (gasp) a third way?

Comment: @jafe, My gamble is [gaff/e](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaff#English). I'm hooked by this, and if a blunder, hope don't get criticism, being caught by a trick.

Comment: I cheated and looked at OP's profile [jafe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AokP.png)

Comment: @Tom Hehehe, clearly a screenshot from the future based on the rep numbers...

Comment: (The way I pronounce it pretty much rhymes with "taffy", btw.)